# flashvars not loading in Flex 4.5 application in Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5, swfobject

I am following [this adobe flashvars example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7feb.html) to try and get flashvars loading in my flex 4.5 application. However, the code is not working. I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong, or differently from the example. here is my index.template.html code (in the html-template folder) which uses swfobject to load the application:

```
        function embedPlayer() {
            var flashvars = {};
            flashvars.userLoggedIn = true;
            flashvars.test = "hello";
            embedSWF(SWF_FILE, SWF_ID, SWF_WIDTH, SWF_HEIGHT, "9.0", "playerProductInstall.swf", flashvars);
        }
```

And here is the simplified code from my flex application:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:d="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008/dt" 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:c="components.*" 
    initialize="mainInit()" 
    creationComplete="doCreationComplete()"
    applicationComplete="_initializer.applicationComplete()"
    xmlns:application="components.application.*" 
    xmlns:gui="com.gui.*" xmlns:main="com.gui.components.main.*" xmlns:photoTray="com.gui.components.main.photoTray.*">

    <fx:Style source="/assets/all.css" />

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.gui.components.main.Initializer;
            import com.gui.components.main.LayoutsController;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;         

            private var _initializer:Initializer;
            private var _layoutsController:LayoutsController;
            public var userLoggedIn:Boolean;                                                                 

            private function mainInit():void {
                _initializer = new Initializer(this);
            }

            private function doCreationComplete():void {
                _initializer.init();
                var params:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters;
                //userLoggedIn = params.userLoggedIn;
                _layoutsController = new LayoutsController(this);
            }   

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

I call FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters (after creationComplete) to try and access flashvars, which is what adobe says is the way to do it in flex 4.5. From my research using Application.application.parameters and root.loaderInfo.parameters are both deprecated.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? My application works fine in flash builder except for flashvars loading on creationComplete.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in flex 3 not sure it applies to flex 4.5

```
Application.application.parameters.userLoggedIn
```

Also on this line

```
//userLoggedIn = params.userLoggedIn;
```

The value of any flash var is a string which you are trying to assign a Boolean.
So do this.

```
//userLoggedIn = Boolean(params.userLoggedIn);
```

Comment: Application.application.parameters is deprecated, and no longer is available in flex 4+. I will note the change to the boolean parameter though. Thanks.